# windows 8 on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, google-chrome-devtools, user-agent

How do I simulate windows 8 behaviour on Chrome or IE? The user agent string needs to be changed, I know that. But somehow I am not getting what I want? This is the string I am using:

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)

Please let me know if this is correct. If not please let me know the right string or any other alternative.

Actually there is an app which needs to be shown for windows 8 platform. No matter which user string I provide the app does not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)

is the right string.

The code had some other issue.